# SwiftUI and RxSwift Observer Closure Behavior

Tags: swift, swiftui, rx-swift

I'm building an iOS app, using RxSwift and SwiftUI. I'm completely new to these frameworks so I was following a few tutorials, but I'm having a hard time figuring how to setup a Observer coupled with SwiftUI whereas I'd like to keep updating my UI as long as my `BehaviorRelay` list of events is updated, here's what I've got in my UI:

```
import SwiftUI
import RxSwift

struct EventsTableView: View {

    private let observer: EventsTableObserver = EventsTableObserver()

    init() {
        observer.setObserver()
        EventViewModel.getAllEvents()
    }

    var body: some View {
            List{
                ForEach(observer.events_view,id: \.id) { event in
                    HStack {
                      Text(event.title)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

class EventsTableObserver {

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var events_view = [Event]()

    func setObserver(){
        EventGroup.shared.events.asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: {
            [unowned self] events in
            self.events_view = events
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

The problem is that apparently after my closure ends, `self.events_view` is not keeping the stored events values as I'd like to, even though the events are being updated. Can someone give me a direction here?

Comment: What is missing here is binding. Once events_view array changes, how would EventsTableView know? so that it can update the view. Apple recommends the ObservedObject of Combine framework which is as good as RxSwift.  If you have specific need to this way, you will have to take care of binding all by yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this using RxSwift. If use the @State property wrapper shouldn't the UI automatically update when the list changes?